# Why type casting inside object definition "doesn't work"?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

Here's a simplistic example:

```
const store = {
    storage: {} as { [key: string]: string },
    add: function (value: string, key: string) {
        this.storage[key] = value
    },
    find: function (key: string) {
        return this.storage[key] || null
    },
}
```

Pointing over `storage:` in VS Code shows

```
(property) storage: {
    [key: string]: string;
}
```

but inside methods pointing over `this.storage` shows `any`.

I've also tried

```
const store = {
    ...
} as { storage: { [key: string]: string } }
```

but still TS doesn't recognize `this.storage` as `{ [key: string]: string }` and hence the deduced type of `find`'s return value is `any`.

What can I do to make `this.storage` be recognized as `{ [key: string]: string }`? Well, beside creating a class for the one time instance.

**PS** I still stumble upon this from time to time, so, although the question got closed, any suggestions on how to debug this are welcome. It may be a bug of VS Code (currently I'm on 1.74.0) since it works as expected in playgrounds provided in comments.

Comment: It is a bit confusing. Can you make an [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play)

Comment: Your issue does not replicate in [a TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBNICcCmMC8MDeAoGu5UQEMBzJALkwF8ZCJMYBtAayQE8LoEBLMYgXQ5RuvGJQA0OPIQAm0igDMArmGBQu4GAAoAboQA2i8vmHExMFu2M9iASkyS8eKAAsuEAHTwEJJMzZ80GF0DJAdRCUd5HjkYJRU1DU0LQRM7bEdHZChFBDAYFzdPAm9SP1YAgB8KmDBFPT0w8SxKIA), the types are inferred correctly.

Comment: @Etheryte oh wow, thanks. That's confusing indeed. I'll investigate more

Answer (score 1):

1. Update your `VSCode`
2. If you are using `typescript` dependency in `package.json`, update it to >4.6
3. try

```
const store = {
    storage: {} as { [key: string]: string },
    add(value: string, key: string) {
        this.storage[key] = value
    },
    find(key: string) {
        return this.storage[key] || null
    },
}
```

Comment: hm, VS Code suggests it uses TS 4.8.2 (it's VS Code 1.71.0) and currently there's no `typescript` dependency in `package.json`

Comment: and in VS Code 1.73.0 (TS 8.4.8) the problem stays